# How to convert this time to hive timestamp

Tags: hive

I have a timestamp value as below:

```
20171020T222028.026 GMT
```

I want to convert this to the following format:

```
2018-12-01 19:35:05
```

Is this possible in Hive ?
Input - 20171020T222028.026 GMT

Output - 2017-10-20 22:20:28

Comment: how do you plan to get that output with the input shown?

Comment: Edited the question with expected output i tried as below but not working. hive (default)> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20171020 222028'), 'yyyymmdd hhmmss');
OK
NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input format needs to be parsed as shown here. No format parameter is needed for `from_unixtime` as the expected output is in the default output format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20171020T222028.026 GMT',"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS z"))
```

Formats:

- `'T'` to escape the literal in the input value.
- `z` for Timezone

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hi how to convert the below timestamp in hive 10/13/2004 12:00:00.000000 AM -> 2004-10-13 12:00:00

Comment: I tried below but giving NULL select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('10/13/2004 12:00:00.000000 AM', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.S z'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
OK
NULL

Comment: in the future you should consider posting a different question..but for now, you can use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('10/13/2004 12:00:00.000000 AM', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.S a'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`. `a` for `AM/PM` , not `z`.